# How to send photo from gallery programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to perform "send photo" functionality. I have a web service method which takes image as parameter. And I need to perform the following:

User clicks on a button, and then photo gallery opens(also be cool to perform send photo from camera i.e camera opens user make photo and then send)
User select photo and click send(then my method should work).

Please tell me is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)upload:(id)sender {
  imagePickerViewController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerViewController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerViewController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerViewController animated:YES];

}


  - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        requestType = 8;
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
        int seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", seconds];
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUploadLink];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];


        NSData* imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        if (imageData) {
            NSLog(@"imageData exists");
        }
        [request setData:imageData withFileName:imageName andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"userfile"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];

    //    [picker release];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some research before you ask, but I'll direct you to look at the `UIImagePickerController`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: Thanks, of course I've provided some search but all that I found was not exactly that I need..

Comment: In any case, UIImagePickerController will let you display to the user of the photo gallery, or the camera. you'll get back a delegate method when the user will pick an image (either from the gallery or the camera) and then you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You only have to build the app using: UIImagePicker for image selection (camera or library) and NSURLConnection for your communications tasks with your services.

You can start here: [Apple iOS Dev Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)